# Expected response to be a <:redirect> but was <200>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've got an issue with my rspec tests and having looked through previous questions I haven't been able to resolve it. The test fails with the above error but the code works in practice, does anyone know how to resolve this?

Rspec:

```
describe "authentication of edit/update pages" do

    before(:each) do
        @user = Factory(:user)
    end

    describe "for non-signed in users" do
        it "should deny access to 'edit'" do
            get :edit, :id => @user
            response.should redirect_to(signin_path)
        end

        it "should deny access to 'update'" do
            put :update, :id => @user, :user => {}
            response.should redirect_to(signin_path)
        end
    end
end
```

Sessions Helper:

```
def deny_access
    redirect_to signin_path, :notice => "Please sign in to access this page."
end
```

Users Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:edit, :update]
  private
    def authenticate
        deny_access unless signed_in?
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should change your code a bit:

```
def deny_access
  redirect_to signin_path, :notice => "Please sign in to access this page." and return
end
```

Comment: Tried this but I'm still getting the error, in fact when I restart the server I get even more failures (with both versions). I might have to abandon these tests. Thanks anyway

Comment: understood, provide more feedback if you want to fix

Comment: indeed, I often end up doing `response.should eq 302` then `response.body.should include "path..."`