# Getting a "Expected response to be a <:redirect>, but was <200>" when trying to pass a test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, shoulda

Just to clarify: I'm new to Ruby and Rails.

I've tryed to solve my problem with the sugestions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048019/rails-tutorial-ch-9-exercise-6-expected-response-to-be-a-redirect-but-was), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966193/rails-rspec-2nd-test-expected-response-to-be-a-redirect-but-was-200) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632905/expected-response-to-be-a-redirect-but-was-200), but they didn't seem to have direct relation with my problem, or I'm too dumb do understand.

I'm trying to test a scenario where I don't update an object and I want my app to redirect. I'm not sure if my controller code is right, I think I'm probably not covering this scenario. Here's my test code:

```
  test "should not update status if nothing has changed" do
    sign_in users(:rodrigo)
    put :update, id: @status
    assert_redirected_to status_path(assigns(:status))
    assert_equal assigns(:status).user_id, users(:rodrigo).id
  end
```

, and my controller update code:

```
  def update
    @status = current_user.statuses.find(params[:id])
    @document = @status.document
    if params[:status] && params[:status].has_key?(:user_id)
      params[:status].delete(:user_id)
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      if @status.update_attributes(params[:status]) &&
         @document && @document.update_attributes(params[:status][:document_attributes])
        format.html { redirect_to @status, notice: 'Status was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @status.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I've already tried to verify if `@status.changed?`, and it really didn't. I'm without options here. If anyone want to help and need more information, I can provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facepalm for me...

I've mentioned in my question:

> I've already tried to verify if `@status.changed?`, and it really didn't.

It did change when I put something different in one of the model attributes, but I've only asked `.changed?` after saving my `@status` model. I'm really sorry about it, I'm yet just figuring out how Ruby on Rais works.

That said, I've came up with a solution to my problem, that was just setting the only one attribute of my model (except the `id`, of course) with the value from the `params[:status]` hash. And **BEFORE** saving it, I ask if `@status.changed?`. If it doesn't, I `redirect_to` the unchanged `@status`, otherwise, I just save it and go through the old code.

Of course that doesn't cover all my scenario, since I also have to check if my `@document` model has changed, but this is not the scope of this question.